# Why does DataTable.Rows not have a .Where() method?

Tags: .net, linq, datatable, datarowcollection

I like the syntax offered by the `.Where()` method that is available for many collections.  However, I've noticed that it is conspicuously absent from some collections.

I'm sure that this has to do with some interface being implemented or not implemented, but beyond that, I would like to know why we don't have a `.Where()` method on DataTable.Rows

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DataRowCollection` only implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<DataRow>`.

An extension method exists - [`DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx) - to effectively "fix" this. You could also just call `table.Cast<DataRow>()` but the [`EnumerableRowCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907979.aspx) returned by `AsEnumerable` has a bit more functionality on it.

So you can write:

```
var query = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
            where ...
            select ...;
```

There are other useful extension methods in [`DataRowExtensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.aspx), most notably `Field`, so you can write:

```
var query = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
            where row.Field<int>("Age") > 18
            select row.Field<string>("Name");
```

Comment: +1: Thanks, Jon.  So... I presume that this `AsEnumerable` method must impose some cost; otherwise the class would implement IEnumerable by default.  Can you tell me what that cost is?